# Trouble compiling rviz on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I've been following the [directions for installing ROS Indigo on Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) and am failing at step 2.3 (building the catkitn workspace). The process fails at step 178 of 185, building rviz. It gets to 2% of that process and then hangs the Pi, which continues to consume 1/4A at 5V but sits there for hours and hours with no progress. The machine also becomes unresponsive to pings, so I think it's totally hosed at that point. Has anyone seen anything like this? Swapping hardware doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks in advance.

Here's the last screen of data before everything goes down:

```
<== Finished processing package [177 of 185]: 'robot_state_publisher'

==> Processing catkin package: 'rviz'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/sshamlian/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/sshamlian/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz'
[  0%] [  1%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/visualization_frame.cpp.o
Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/visualization_manager.cpp.o
[  2%] [  2%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/view_manager.cpp.o
Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/visualizer_app.cpp.o
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204422/trouble-compiling-rviz-on-raspberry-pi-2/) by [Shamlian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21794/shamlian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2015-03-08**:
This may not solve your problem, but  try the build with make -j2 instead of -j4.  This will run two sets of jobs concurrently rather than four.  The RPi2 doesnt have enough memory for 4 jobs and will thrash quite a bit and then die on large builds but will bld MUCH faster with two.

**Comment by [Shamlian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21794/shamlian/) on 2015-03-09**:
This helps, but doesn't completely build. Now, I get to 94% on rviz's build, which is probably worth opening another question for. For the original question, though, this seems to be the answer: make must be invoked with -j2, so the wiki should be modified accordingly.

**Comment by [Shamlian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21794/shamlian/) on 2015-03-10**:
Ok; I got rviz to make using the patch suggested in the following question: http://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/ . I'll update the wiki accordingly if I get catkin_make_isolated --install to complete.

**Comment by [Shamlian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21794/shamlian/) on 2015-03-10**:
This worked and the wiki has been updated. I made an answer below that has both of these steps, but I don't have enough "karma" to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, a patch needs to be applied to rviz as described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/). Then, as @corb suggested, running make -j2 from .../ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz will allow the build to succeed; once this is complete, catkin_make_isolated will proceed as normal. I have updated the wiki accordingly, though someone will probably want to check my formatting. Thanks to everyone for all the help! (You can probably run catkin_make_isolated with `--make-args -j2` after patching, but I didn't test that.)

---

Originally posted by [Shamlian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21794/shamlian/) with karma: 56 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yuwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/22343/yuwang/) on 2015-05-04**:
when i failed, i running sudo make -j2 from .../ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz, but i got this "-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Makefile:1030: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
",please help me.i am a new.

**Comment by [yuwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/22343/yuwang/) on 2015-05-05**:
I fix it by building rviz alone(remove all the packages from .../ros_catkin_ws/src excpet rviz), then run catkin_make_isolated with --make -j2 -l2.